How to retrieve a single value from a query but still allow it to be ordered in Spring JPA with PostgreSQL?
Let's say that I have an entity that looks liks this:
@Entity
class User {
    @Id
    val id: UUID
    val name: String
    val createdAt: OffsetDateTime
}

And I want to create a query that returns all the ids that I have on the DB, but ordered by createdAt.
Initially I tried:
interface UserRepository : JpaRepository<User, UUID> {
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT u.id FROM User u ORDER BY u.createdAt")
    fun getIds(): List<UUID>
}

But then I got the error SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list. So I added the createdAt field to the select clause:
interface UserRepository : JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.createdAt FROM User u ORDER BY u.createdAt")
    fun getIds(): List<Long>
}

But then I got the error Could not convert '[Ljava.lang.Object;' to 'java.util.UUID' using 'org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.UUIDJavaType' to wrap, which makes sense as I'm trying to convert the returned values into a single UUID.
What should I do to get only the ids from this query but still allow it to be ordered by createdAt?

do you really have multiple users with the same id? If so, what do you expect if the user and its shadow were created at different times?

@JGH hmm yes, this example didn't show my exact scenario. In my query I also have do make a join with another table in a OneToMany relationship which ends up returning multiple rows with the same id, that's why I need the distinct.

You can use a different query:
SELECT u.id FROM User u GROUP BY u.id ORDER BY MIN(u.createdAt);


Or even this:
SELECT u.id FROM User u ORDER BY u.createdAt

@RomanRastiehaiev That's a different query and when the id is not unique, you might get multiple results for the same id.

I assumed that this is a user's ID and it can't be duplicated. Especially when the field is annotated with @Id (usually because it's primary key).

@RomanRastiehaiev When your assumption is right, there wouldn't be a need for DISTINCT in the first place.
